# Converting Duden dictionaries for Stardict/Goldendict

Tags: file-format, encodings, binary-format

I’ve a bunch of first-class German dictionaries by Duden (the main German dictionary publisher) which, sadly, use a closed proprietary data format and their dedicated Duden-Bibliothek application ([Information in German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duden-Bibliothek)).

I’m usually using [Goldendict](http://goldendict.org/) on my tablet. Is there any possibility to convert my dictionaries to Stardict/Goldendict format so I can use them on my Android devices ?

I’ve looked into [stardict-tools](https://code.google.com/p/stardictproject/) but can’t convert.

Comment: Could you post a sample of each files ? Could you also please rephrase "can't convert", what do you mean: - does not work - throw an exception - return a file that cannot be read...

Comment: It means conversion script crashes. It expects .utf file and when given one, it just crashes. Seems it cannot read the format at all. It also doesn't produce any meaningful output.

Please contact me for samples. These files are copyrighted, cannot post them here.

Comment: since you did not add any info about yourself in SO, let's do it the other way around. Send me an email with this utf file. thx

Comment: did you check [stardicter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stardicter)

Comment: Stardicter supports only free, very low quality dictionaries. Duden is a proprietary format. Android app is totally unusable and so are another great sources of dictionaries for many languages Millennium and Lingea. The way I see it, trying various tools blindly won't help.

Comment: Well, @summer.breeze, intriguing question. Personally I've had some version of those purchased as well some years ago. Naturally what you'd first look at are not the files themselves, but the respective code accessing the files. Haven't touched that thing in years, though. Will see if I find that old dictionary. Ever since the spelling _deformities_ I kinda refrain from supporting this craze. Found it. It's from 2011. Will see what I can make of it. No guarantee it'll be anything similar to your stuff, though.

Comment: would you still be interested in those files, @0xC0000022L ? I like your idea of inspecting code, not the format itself. Wouldn't it also be possible to loop through the dictionary with intents? Book readers support highlighting a word and then fetching result from the program in a popup window: https://github.com/raghavkc/fbreaderj2/blob/master/assets/dictionaries.xml. I know, a bit crazy.